# Parse facebook comments

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to parse FB comments JSON, which I get from

```
 var url = http://graph.facebook.com/comments?id={{ url_of_the_page }}
```

Using jQuery, I am trying to get `data.id` and other items from the response by:

```
 $j.getJSON(url, function (item) {            
        console.log(item);              
    });
```

However, they stick an URL object at the top, so it's:

```
item
 {{ url_of_the_page }}
     data 
         [0]
            id
            ...
```

How do I access `id` and other properties? `item.{{ url_of_the_page }}.data` does not work..

JSON sample:

```
  {
 "http://www.mysiteurl.com": {
  "data": [
     {
        "id": "10150212811760417_27834638",
        "from": {
           "name": "Tomas Tomas",
           "id": "100000606151004"
        },
        "message": "test",
        "created_time": "2011-11-22T14:21:42+0000"
     },
     {
        "id": "10150212811760417_27835460",
        "from": {
           "name": "Tomas Tomas",
           "id": "100000606151004"
        },
        "message": "ThanksGiving!",
        "created_time": "2011-11-22T14:51:23+0000"
     },
     {
        "id": "10150212811760417_27835931",
        "from": {
           "name": "Tomas Tomass",
           "id": "100000606151004"
        },
        "message": "3rd comment",
        "created_time": "2011-11-22T15:08:49+0000"
     }
  ],
  "paging": {
     "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/comments?ids=http\u00253A\u00252F\u00252Fwww.mywebsite.com&limit=25&offset=25"
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: If you could post some actual JSON it would be helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
item["url_of_the_page"].data[0].id
```

Comment: I think it’s `item["url_of_the_page"].data[0].id` (assuming `url_of_the_page` not to be the name of a variable but the string of the actual url).

Comment: I added quotes that you'd need.

Comment: Yes offcourse the url string should be in double or single quotes. I think that is understood.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of using `for` loops to get your data from the JSON object: http://jsfiddle.net/jasper/4XVMp/1/

```
for (url in json) {
    console.log(url);
    for (index in json[url].data) {
        console.log('--> ' + index);
        for (key in json[url].data[index]) {
            console.log('---->' + key + ' = ' + json[url].data[index][key]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with the `students.item["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data[i].id` option a bit. Finally got it working with `students["http://www.myurl.com"].comments.data[i].id`

```
var students = {
    "http://www.myurl.com": {
        "comments": {
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": "123456778",
                    "from": {
                        "name": "Rohit",
                        "id": "1000005"
                    },
                    "message": "Hey ROhit",
                    "can_remove": false,
                    "created_time": "2012-09-03T03:16:01+0000",
                    "like_count": 0,
                    "user_likes": false
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```